# Python script completes, but Windows Task Scheduler shows running

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a small script to clear out stopped torrents in Transmission. The script writes a log, does it's work in Transmission, and exits. Script below:

```
#Module Imports#
import transmissionrpc
import os
import logging
import sys
import datetime

#Set variables before main() function
logdir = 'D:\\scripts\\logs'
myDate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d")
myTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
myDateTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d %H:%M")

if not os.path.exists(logdir):
    os.makedirs(logdir)

logger = logging.getLogger('transmissionrpc')
logdate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d %H%M")
logfile = logdir + "\\CTS-" + logdate + '.log'
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info("Begin Transmission clean")

tc = transmissionrpc.Client('localhost', port = 9091, user = 'USER', password = 'PASS')
for t in tc.get_torrents():
    if t.status == 'stopped':
        tc.remove_torrent(t.id, delete_data = True)
        print ('Removing Torrent %s - %s' % (t.id, t.name))
        logger.info('Removing Torrent %s - %s' % (t.id, t.name))

logger.info("No more stopped torrents. Exiting")
sys.exit()
```

Running the script in Tasks Scheduler as `pythonw D:\Path\to\script.py`

How can I get Task Scheduler to properly show the script has ended?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your code:

```
import os
print(os.getpid())
```

Compare the number that it prints with the process ID in the Task Scheduler. If you don't see a match, your script must be running in another process.